# Created a for loop in R to (ggplot) multiple columns with one corresponding column (x), how to stop when it sees a 0 and move on to the next column?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

I created a a time v. concentration model in R for ggplot, the first set of data points did not have 0's so I thought'd it be ok. I then created one sheet with my Elapsed Days (x) and Concentrations (y) and created a for loop. The for loop comes up with an error because there are values inside some columns that have 0s. Id like for it to stop plotting when it hits a 0 in the for loop and move on to the next set of data points

Any help would be appreciated!

```
for(i in 1:24){


  i = i + 2
  x <- alldata1$Elapsed.Days  
  y <- as.matrix(alldata1[i])

  df <- data.frame(x, y)

  myFunction(x, y, df)

}
```

Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

since there are zero values, but Im a bit unsure.

Comment: Did you log-transform the data and that's why you have `log(0)` = `-Inf` in your loop maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an if condition for where it finds `0` and move to next

ex:

```
for(n in c(1,2,4,0,6,0,8,0)) {
  if(n==0) next # skip wherever it gets 0 to next iteration
  print(n)
}
```

Output

```
 1 
 2
 4
 6
 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Geekzeus' answer is perfectly fine, I would just like to bring to your attention that there are also slightly more formal ways of dealing with errors and warnings. If you would have a look at the code below:

```
output <- tryCatch({myFunction(x, y, df)},
                   warning = function(cond) {NULL},
                   error = function(cond) {NULL})
if (is.null(output)) {
  next()
} else {
  return(output)
}
```

What will happen here is that R tries to evaluate `myFunction(x, y, df)`, when it encounters an error it will provide the error condition to the `function(cond){NULL}`, which will do nothing with `cond` but instead assigns `NULL` to `output`. Subsequently the code will continue.

Here is an example to play around with:

```
foo <- function(i) {if (i == 3) stop("Error")}

for(i in 1:5) {
  print(i)
  out <- tryCatch({foo(i)}, error = function(cond){NULL})
  if (is.null(out)) next()
}
```

The above will print all 5 numbers, even though it encountered an error when `i == 3`.

Its a good way to specify what should happen when your code encounters an error, but is not a substitute for debugging your code to prevent errors in the first place.